# Canvas: refresh screen on touch

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm trying to make something like Battleships.
By this time I've managed to random spawn and draw them on canvas.
But there's another problem: in the game user will touch the cell and that cell will be painted as yellow (if hit) or draw a dot (if miss).

As far as I see, everything that displays on canvas must be writted in onDraw() method.

The question is: how can I make screen refresh with new data when user touches the screen?

Now the screen looks like this: 
[image]

This time the ships are visible for debug

Comment: call invalidate() to refresh the draw.

Comment: Will it erase previous drawings?

Comment: call to invalidate will call ondraw() it won't erase until you have erase code in ondraw

Comment: And if I want to do differrent things at different time? Make if-clauses in onDraw() ?

Comment: you can use if else in onDraw(). call to invalidate will only refresh your draw

Comment: can I call invalidate only for selected area on screen?

Comment: if you have different vies you can refresh the views by calling invalidate only on that particular view

Comment: No, I have one view. Can I refresh only some area on View?